# the best way to remove the first char of a given string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Using `jquery`, `underscore` or pure `javascript` what is the best way to remove the first char of a given string?

I will make something like this:

```
"aamerica".substring(1,"aamerica".length);

"aamerica".slice(1);
```

Is better to use slice or substring?

Comment: Um... that is the best way.  What is wrong with that approach?  Could be wrapped in a function if you do it a lot.

Answer (score 11):

You would actually be fine doing:

```
"aamerica".substring(1);
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zktGF/1/)**

[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)'s second parameter is optional:

> string.substring(indexA[, indexB])

Answer (score 4):

```
"aamerica".substring(1);
```

your `"aamerica".length;` [is unecessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

quote from doc:

> string.substring(indexA[, indexB])
>
> If indexB is omitted, substring extracts characters to the end of the string.

You are in total 3 options:

- `"aamerica".substring(1);`
- `"aamerica".slice(1);`
- `"aamerica".substr(1);`

All three methods have [equivalent performance](http://jsperf.com/substring-extraction-methods-substring-substr-slice).

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice: `"aamerica".slice(1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it much better than you already are.

You can, however, omit the 2nd parameter when you want your substring to go to the end of the string.

`var s = "aamerica".substring(1);`